# Behavior of __LINE__ when used in a macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Why does `__LINE__` evaluate differently based on whether it's used inside a function-like macro or a regular function?

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define A() printf("%d\n",__LINE__);

int main(void) {
/* 6 */  A();
/* 7 */  A(
/* 8 */    );
/* 9 */  printf("%d\n",__LINE__
/* 10 */  );
}
```

I would expect to get:

```
6
7
9
```

But instead we get (using clang-1000.10.44.4):

```
6
8
9
```

Note how in the function-like macro spread over lines 7 & 8, the last line occupied is used, rather than the first.

GCC's documentation is light on details: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Why do I care? I'm writing a parser that needs to find the line numbers of all instances of the macro `A` in such a way as to line up with what `__LINE__` will return. It is much harder to find the *last* line of the macro usage rather than the *first* due to the need to parse possibly escaped arguments.

Comment: Ultimately you will need to do the parsing correctly anyway, as there may be macros within macro arguments and other complications.

Comment: I am suprised to see, that the output changed with last gcc version. So: no worries. When you update to gcc9.1 the output will match expected(!), see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/FaDSPO). I am also suprised to see there is no double `;;` on the end of the second line in `main` when using `gcc -E`.

Comment: @Kamil: The missing `;` is a gift from godbolt. If you disable the filtering of "comment-only lines" (the `//` button), you'll see the semicolons on both gcc versions.

Comment: @KamilCuk #1 godbolt is AWESOME, #2 I'm terrified that this behavior changes in gcc 9. That's enough evidence to make me reconsider my approach to logging.

Comment: If your parser wants to parse C, it must also deal with backslash newline in the middle of a token, such as `__LI\\nNE__` somewhere, or `MA\\nCRO()`. I believe the C Standard leaves the value of `__LINE__` unspecified for these.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C implementation does not replace the `A()` macro until it sees the closing `)`. That `)` appears on line 8, so that is the point at which macro replacement occurs.

The specifics of `__LINE__` with regard to macro replacement are not well specified by the C standard. You should likely not rely on a particular behavior here. Certainly the C implementation **cannot** replace the `A()` macro while it has read only up to line 7, as it does not know what is coming yet. Once it has seen the closing `)`, then, as it replaces the macro, it might consider the replacement tokens to be occurring on line 7 or on line 8 or on some mix—the C standard is not specific about this; line numbers are largely irrelevant to C semantics at this point, and the `__LINE__` macro is largely a convenience for debugging and other development work, not a feature for production programs (although it may have some uses for them).

In the `printf`, the C implementation recognizes the `__LINE__` macro as soon as it sees the end of the line. (Actually, the parsing is more involved; the input has been tokenized, but the effect is the `__LINE__` token is recognized when the end-of-line character is examined.) It is on line 9, so it is replaced by `9`. The fact it is an argument to `printf` is irrelevant. The C implementation does not have the process the `printf` in order to replace the `__LINE__` token that appears on line 9; they do not interact.

Comment: The first point here is important, but the second is *crucial*.  The standard provides no basis for judging the observed behavior either more or less correct than the OP's expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tests on my own, you can not rely on a behaviour here as even gcc changed its behaviour across versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                            
#define ShowLine() printf("__LINE__ evals to %d", __LINE__);                                                                                                  
int main()                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                             
    ShowLine(                                                                                                                                                
              );                                                                                                                                              
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

This code shows

- 5 with gcc 11
- 6 with gcc 7
- 6 with clang13